# How to reflect method which be stored in object

Tags: c#, reflection

My code is:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> services;
public void AddService<T>( string serviceName, T func )
{
    if ( services.ContainsKey( serviceName ) )
    {
        services.Add( serviceName, func );
    }
}


public void A()
{
    /* doing */
}


public void B( string a )
{
    /* doing */
}


public string C( string a )
{
    /* doing */
    return(a);
}


[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    services = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    AddService<Action>( "Aservice", A );
    AddService<Action<string> >( "Bservice", B );
    AddService<Func<string, string>>( "Cservice", C );


    foreach ( var service in services )
    {
        /*
         * How to print these service like this:
         * void A()
         * void B(string xxx)
         * string C(string xxx)
         */
    }
}
```

I wanna stroe some function into `Dictionary` as service, and call them when needed.
Because i could not sure the added service's type, so i use `T` to replace `Action<string>`,`Func<string>` or others.

I can use these code to call `Aservice`, just need convert `object` to Aservice's type

```
var a = services["Aservice"] as Action;
a();
```

But when a third part want call any service, he must know the service's type.

So, i wanna print these service's type, include argumentType, returnType, functionName.

I try it use reflection, but no good result.

I could not use `System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo` because of cannot access internal.

Can you help me?

Comment: `service.GetType().GetMethods()` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell I tried. But these methods in `Type` will be returned.